# Problem with vertex painting

Tags: vertex-paint

I'm trying to do a low-poly tutorial and I want to use vertex painting to paint the island but the brush doesn't paint... I'm a begginer, please someone can help me?

[image]

Comment: https://youtu.be/AnRQhH3fEDY
You might want to watch this, I don't think that vertex paint is actually for changing the colors of your mesh.

Comment: You're in a rendered preview, and the material you're showing is not referencing your vertex color layer at all.  Consider creating a "vertex color" node, giving it the name of your vertex color layer (like "Col") and plugging it into the Base Color input on your material's Principled BSDF.